I have a list of 7 Excel row numbers and 7 Excel column letters, how can I combine these into a list of 49 cells?
I have a list of columns (F,S,AE,AQ,BC,BO,CA) with a certain heading (parameter) and a list of rows (10,21,32,43,54,65,76) with a certain heading (location). I want to find the max value in these 49 cells. These rows and columns may change with across multiple work sheets and could increase in number.
These lists were found using:
=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(,0,(IFERROR(ADDRESS(--(B:B="TAG 2-6")*ROW(B:B),1,4),""))),"A",","),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(,0,(IFERROR(ADDRESS(--(B:B="TAG 2-6")*ROW(B:B),1,4),""))),"A",","))-1)
I would like to end up with a way to create an array or list of cells from these rows and columns, so I can just use =MAX(....)
This will go on a separate summary worksheet, so ideally this needs to be in one cell.
I have tried using multiplication, but as the rows are text I just get a 0.
There may be an obvious way to do this, but I am not familiar with using arrays in Excel

=MAX(MAXIFS(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},F:F,S:S,AE:AE,AQ:AQ,BC:BC,BO:BO,CA:CA),B:B,"TAG 2-6"))

If you want to dynamically choose the columns based on a HeaderValue:  =MAX(MAXIFS(INDEX(A:CC,FILTER(COLUMN(A:CC),A1:CC1="HeaderValue"),0),B:B,"TAG 2-6"))

I tried to suggest it might be an XY problem in Staging Ground and therefore better answered as @Scott Craner has commented than through inappropriate use of indirect, but it had no effect and the question came through unchanged :-(

Thanks Scott. Tom, I didn't see your comment before it was posted but you are right. I had used the formula in my question to get the rows and columns and did not consider that it would not need be in the overall solution.

The solution is simple enough:
=MAX(INDIRECT({"F","S","AE","AQ","BC","BO","CA"}&{10;21;32;43;54;65;76}))

Or:
=MAX(INDIRECT(LetterVector&NumberVector))

where LetterVector and NumberVector should be horizontal and vertical vectors or vice versa. The vector means the array of 1xY or Yx1 cells.
For example:
=MAX(INDIRECT(A1:A7&B1:H1))

Or:
=MAX(INDIRECT(A1:A7&TRANSPOSE(B1:B7)))




A
B




F
10


S
21


AE
32


AQ
43


BC
54


BO
65


CA
76



LetterVector and NumberVector can be dynamic arrays as well.
The sample:


Simple is not always best. INDIRECT will recalculate at any change anywhere in the workbook and will make files slow or unworkable. If we can we should avoid using it. If we know the sheet we don't really need to use it. INDEX (like Scott Craners showcased) is a better choice then.

@P.b I didn't bother to analyze the formulas in the question, answered as it. Unfortunately, OP has not provided the source data.

How is it going?
